# FullCalendar ListWeek view throwing error when event is in multiweek

Tags: fullcalendar

I have an event starting 1/26/2018 and ending on 1/28/2018.

[image: Calendar Month View]

When I go to ListWeek view, I am getting following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'startMs' of undefined
throws at ... fullcalendar.js:17616:61 TypeError: Cannot read property 
'startMs' of undefined
at members.constructor.componentFootprintToSegs (fullcalendar.js:17616)
at members.constructor.eventFootprintToSegs (fullcalendar.js:5238)
at members.constructor.eventFootprintsToSegs (fullcalendar.js:5217)
at members.constructor.renderEventsPayload (fullcalendar.js:5527)
at members.constructor.callChildren (fullcalendar.js:4866)
at members.constructor.renderEventsPayload (fullcalendar.js:4427)
at members.constructor.executeEventsRender (fullcalendar.js:10241)
at eval (fullcalendar.js:9917)
at constructor.runTaskFunc (fullcalendar.js:2506)
at constructor.runTask (fullcalendar.js:2636)
```

`ListWeek` is working fine if event in within the week range but throws error if event spread across multiple weeks.

I get same error on `ListMonth` if even spreads in multiple month.

Is it a bug?

Comment: What version of the FullCalendar are you using? Try to update to version 3.6 or higher and it should be fixed. 

 1. https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/pull/3837

Comment: Thankyou Diego Armando Maradona. I upgraded to latest version 3.8.0 which resolved the error.